# Starlink constellation: why so many satellites?

Tags: space-communications

I'm carefully studying the constellation of satellites that Elon Musk has been setting up in recent years, the star link constellation. currently it has more than 4000 satellites working in harmony with each other, located in low earth orbit. My question is, why put so many satellites, when a smaller quantity could be shipped with larger and more powerful satellites for data transmission? the signal would be higher and possibly the lower costs. could someone give me an answer?

[Starlink map](https://satellitemap.space/)

Comment: "Elon Musk" and "smaller quantity" are concepts that don't mix well.

Comment: Using "multiple" mini satellites has one advantage that continuous operation can be more easily maintained when a satellite has a problem... With less number of larger satellites, smooth opration is harder to maintain...

Comment: Furthemore, requiring "min ping delay" for a satellite internet communication also suggests low orbiting, but then surface signal "coverage" area is limited, and you need large number of low orbiting sats for global surface coverage...

Comment: In addition to the smaller coverage area given by low earth orbit, this also provides a data capacity benefit given by spatial frequency reuse. This is similar to the motivation for smaller cells in high urban areas for terrestrial mobile communications.

Comment: @DanBoschen so it can be said to be a very crafty move regarding terrestrial coverage

Comment: @Fat32 Very clear, thanks for the explanation. In fact, reading several articles and looking at the map I sent, I did not take too much into consideration the fact that the satellites of the constellation travel in low orbit, it is a fundamental detail at this point.

Comment: @RiccardoBarbo "very crafty": no, it's the *obvious* move, when you ever had anything to do with building a cellular network, or a satcom network. Also, such constellations have been discussed since at least the 1980s, it's just that they were commercially infeasible, and technologically challenging, due to lack of experience with cheaper smallsats. "Crafty" is not the right word here; I think "possible due to massive investment of capital" is the right word. (don't get me wrong, there's a lot of innovation in Starlink, just that the idea of LEO satellite constellation isn't innovative itself)

Comment: Btw. I have an extrmely negative opinion about A.M. The way he makes his fortune is extremely questionable... Regarding the "money making" model of whole stock market, derivatives, bit-coins, crypto-currencies... all they can say is "they are using their computer for mining :-))))))" the "new" fashion term for "fraud" and indirect theft...

Comment: -RiccardoBarbo : the "low orbit" decision probably was guided mainly by the reasons indicated by @DanBoschen